# Android 5 Rotation Vector Sensor not being accurate

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I've encountered an issue with the rotation sensor, the one with `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` type. The reading from the sensor seems not to be accurate, or it is disturbed by something, it's hard for me to tell. This is the code I'm using to aquire the actual rotation of the device:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
        if (prevRotMatrix == null) {
            prevRotMatrix = new float[16];
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(prevRotMatrix, event.values);
        } else {
            float[] deltas = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotMatrix, event.values);
            SensorManager.getAngleChange(deltas, rotMatrix, prevRotMatrix);

            rotXVal += (float) Math.toDegrees(deltas[1]);
            rotYVal += (float) Math.toDegrees(deltas[2]);
            rotZVal += (float) Math.toDegrees(deltas[0]);

            client.rotX(rotXVal);
            client.rotY(rotYVal);
            client.rotZ(rotZVal);

            System.arraycopy(rotMatrix, 0, prevRotMatrix, 0, rotMatrix.length);
        }
    }
}
```

The `rotXVal`, `rotYVal` and `rotZVal` are all zero at the beginning.
 The problem is, the values I'm getting are somehow disturbed. Devices movement is generally vizualized by them, but very often some invalid values show up. Often when I rotate the device in one direction, the reading shows up the valid rotation, but after that there is an invalid 'feedback' to the opposite direction, usually smaller then the proper movement.
The important thing is that the situation only happens for me on the Android Lollipop device (Samsung Galaxy S6). I was testing this on KitKat as well (Samsung Galaxy Note 4) and the same code worked just fine.
I noticed the same behavior when running [this RotationVectorDemo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/RotationVectorDemo.java). The same distortion type on Lollipop, but works fine on KitKat.
I wonder if someone could help me figuring out how to solve or workaround the issue. Or maybe I should drop it and use some other sensor?

Comment: I encountered the same issue but only on the S6 (Android  6) every other device regardless of the android version works.